# Plone form-folder auto-scrolls to bottom

Tags: plone

I have a plone form-folder which I misuse as a page here:

http://www.icg.tugraz.at/project/caleydo/stratomex

I'd like to have the contact form at the bottom of the page so I'm using form folders and put the text in the form prologue.

Now, the only Issue I have is that plone tells my browser to auto-scroll to the bottom of the page, where the form is located. Is it somehow possible to turn that off, or will I have to resort to some anchor-tag based linking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the culprit is Plone's first_input_focus.js javascript, which automatically focuses the first form input on a page. You can disable it in portal_javascripts in the ZMI, but keep in mind that will remove this functionality sitewide.

Comment: You could also put a TAL condition on the javascript to hide it for a specific page or specific section of the site.